# Problemas con PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estoy tratando de modificar un `excel` con php, una vez que le cambio lo que necesito se supone que lo tengo que guardar, una vez guardado lo descargo, entonces el problema surgue que cuando lo descargo y lo abro me dice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siendo que no hago ningun cambio solo lo abro y le doy cerrar, se supone que no me deberia de mostrar ese mensaje ya que cuando lo modifico lo guardo. mi código es el siguiente:

```
    $fecha_inicial = $this->input->post ( 'date_start' );
    $nombre_ruta = $this->input->post ( 'route_name' );
    $archivo = str_replace(" ","_",$this->input->post ( 'name' ));
    $ext = strrchr($archivo, ".");
    $hoja_excel = "./plantillas_excel/".$archivo;
    $this->load->library('excel');

    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($hoja_excel);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($hoja_excel);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    //Indicamos que se pare en la hoja uno del libro
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $data = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A2:N2000');

    $numeroCelda = 1;
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $numeroCelda++;
        if($row[0]!=null)
        {

            $fecha_nombre = str_replace ("-" , "" , $fecha_inicial );
            //$objWorksheet->getCell('A'.$numeroCelda)->getValue()
            $objWorksheet->SetCellValue('A'.$numeroCelda, $nombre_ruta." ".$fecha_nombre);
            $valDateB = $objWorksheet->getCell('B'.$numeroCelda)->getValue();
            if($valDateB!=null && is_numeric ( $valDateB )){
                    $valB= PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($valDateB);
                    $valDateB = $valB->format($fecha_inicial.' H:i:s');
                    $objWorksheet->SetCellValue('B'.$numeroCelda, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($valDateB));
            }

            $valDateN = $objWorksheet->getCell('N'.$numeroCelda)->getValue();
            if($valDateN!=null && is_numeric ( $valDateN )){
                $valN= PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($valDateN);
                $valDateN = $valN->format($fecha_inicial.' H:i:s');
                   $objWorksheet->SetCellValue('N'.$numeroCelda, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($valDateN));
            }   
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $inputFileType);
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header('Content-Disposition:inline;filename="'.$fecha_nombre.'.xls"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

si alguien sabe donde la estoy regando se lo agradecería mucho ya que apenas ando metiendole mano a php de lleno...

Comment: de casualidad le das hablitar edicion cuando lo abres? has probado con otro office, 2013,2016,2010?

Comment: no, solo lo descargo y le doy abrir, al querer cerrarlo me marca esa ventana de guardar cambios

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que tu instalación de Excel requiera hacer una conversión para poder mostrar el archivo ya sea debido a que el archivo está mal formado o bien porque se trata de un formato antiguo.

La extensión `.xls` corresponde a versiones antiguas de Excel. En la versión 2007 se introdujo la extensión `.xlsx`. Nótese que desde entonces ya han pasado varias versiones, sin contar los paquetes de servicio. En mayo de 2017, la versión actual es la 2016.

Comment: Vi algo muy extraño, cuando lo descargo pesa 16KB, pero cuando le doy guardar me lo hace mas grande a 34KB...

Comment: A mí no me parece extraño porque ya me ha pasado varias veces (: Cuando le das guardar, ¿en qué extensión lo guardas? ¿Qué versión de Excel estás usando?

Comment: se queda en la misma versión, cuando se descarga esta en .xls cuando le doy guardar al abrirlo se queda con la misma extensión pero aumenta su peso. esta en  excel 97-2003

Comment: Además de si cambiabas la extensión del archivo, te preguntaba por la versión de la aplicación.

Comment: En cualquier caso, es posible que PHPExcel no esté formando bien los archivos en formato .xls según la versión de la aplicación Excel que estes usando. Por lo pronto no te podría ayudar en específico con PHPExcel pues no lo uso y no pienso usarlo pronto.